# Accessing properties of html element inside javascript function using $(this) gives undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes

I am calling a function `test()` on an anchor tag like this:-

```
<a class="link" onclick="test();">Hello</a>
```

And I am trying to access the class of the anchor inside the function test():-

```
function test()
{
  alert($(this).attr("class"));
}
```

But this alerts `undefined`. I know that calling `onclick=test(this);` instead and having the following function works:-

```
function test(obj)
{
  alert($(obj).attr("class"));
}
```

But, I wanted to access the properties of the element (on which the function is called) without passing a `this`. Just be able to `get`/`set` properties of the element (on which the function is called). Is it possible? How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario we need to make sure that HTML element owns that function which you wanna call upon click. What u actually doing is that u are using onclick attribute which just takes ***string*** parameter and completely oblivious of everything else.

In order to make HTML element owner of the function you need to map onclick property **completely** with your own custom function. In JavaScript you do that like that

```
element.onclick = doSomething;
```

So our code will be something like

```
<div id="element">Click</div>
<script>
function doSomething(){
    this.style.color= "#000000"
}
document.getElementById("element").onclick = doSomething;
</script>
```

here is the working example http://www.jsfiddle.net/VMCmb/1/.

Also please take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Comment: Simpler answer and nice links... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`this` is "The object on which this function was called", so for `foo.test()`, `this` is `foo` inside `test`. If you don't specify an object, it defaults to `window` so in your code `this === window` since you are calling (implicitly) `window.test()`.

Forget about intrinsic event attributes. They are ugly and do not lend themselves to [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

Instead, use JavaScript to assign your event handlers. jQuery, which you are already using, provides a number of ways to do this, including `click`. Pass the function you want to call as the argument to it.

```
jQuery('.link').click(test);
```

When the click event fires, it will now call something akin to `HTMLElementNode.test()` instead of `HTMLElementNode.onclick()` so `this` will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because "this" is a special free variable in Javascript: it is bound by the context of the caller.
Passing this is a better and safer way of doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this method -

Pass this as a parameter -

```
<a class="link" onclick="test(this);">Hello</a>
```

Jquery code will be -

```
function test(obj)
{
  alert($(obj).attr("class"));
}
```